# Are Using Remote Url or local path same performance wise when copying?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, https, copy

Question is self-explanatory.
I have a file `/var/www/example/filez/file1.exe`

It can also be accessed via `https://www.abc.xyz/filez/file1.exe`.

Now my question is if I have a script
`/var/www/example/script.php`

Is Trying 
`copy('/var/www/example/filez/file1.exe',$target_location)`

**less expensive than**

`copy('https://www.abc.xyz/filez/file1.exe',$target_location)` ?

Or it does it not matter?

Comment: It does matter. The filesystem is faster than a connection over the network, even if the target is the machine itself. It still will be a connection over the "internet", with the overhead of a DNS lookup, TCP/IP connection and transfering back the response over HTTP.

Comment: how much faster will be the filesystem ? is it negligible ?

Comment: Filesystem is always faster and depending on the network, latency, etc. it will be quite noticeable. If possible you should always use filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

apart from parse the url to the local path, there is no difference copy the same file to same destination.

Comment: not to same destination.  say copying `filez/user1/file.exe` to `filez/user2/file.exe`

Comment: not to same destination.  say copying `filez/user1/file.exe` to `filez/user2/file.exe` is faster or copying `https://www.abc.xyz/filez/user1/file.exe` to `filez/user2/file.exe` is faster ?

Comment: all files are in same server. im just asking using https are there any overhead in performance

Comment: the second http path will treaded as the local path, then use the local copy, not trans file by the htttp

Comment: and the two copy scheme, is copy the same file from same source position to same target same position.